# PHP to MYSQL - Putting a PHP Array into a MYSQL table and updating it periodically?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Sorry if this has been answered, but if it had been answered already, I can't find it anywhere. So, from the beginning then. Lets say I had a `member` table and I want to store in it what their top 3 interests are.  There is `$row` that has all the usual things to identify them `userID` and `password` etc.. and I had a further 3 columns which were labelled `top3_1`, `top3_2` & `top3_3` to put each of their interests in from a post form.

If instead I wanted to store this data as a PHP Array instead (using 1 column instead of 3) is there a way to store it as readable data when you open the PHPmyadmin?

At the moment all what it says is array and when I call it back to the browser (say on a page where they could review and update their interests) it displays 'a' as top3_01 'r' as top3_02 and 'r' as top3_03 (in each putting what would be 'array' as it appears in the table if there were 5 results. Does anyone know what I mean?

For example:

If we had a form which collected the top 3 interests to put in a table called users,

```
<form action="back_to_same_page_for_processing.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     <input name="top3_01" type="text" value="enter interest number 1 here" />
     <input name="top3_02" type="text" value="enter interest number 2 here" />
     <input name="top3_03" type="text" value="enter interest number 3 here" />
     <input type="submit" name="update_button" value=" Save and Update! " />

</form> // If my quick code example for this form is not correct dont worry its not the point im getting at :)
```

And they put 'bowling' in top3_01, 'running' in top3_02 and 'diving' in top3_03 and we catch that on the same page with some PHP at the top -->

```
if (isset($_POST)['update_button']) {
    $top3_01 = $_POST['top3_01']; // i.e, 'bowling' changing POST vars to local vars
    $top3_02 = $_POST['top3_02']; // i.e, 'running'
    $top3_03 = $_POST['top3_03']; // i.e, 'diving'
}
```

With me so far? If I had a table which had 3 columns (1 for each interest) I could put something like -

```
include('connect_msql.php');

mysql_query("Select * FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND blah blah blah");
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET top3_01='$top3_01', top3_02='$top3_02', top3_03='$top3_03' WHERE id='$id'");
```

And hopefully if I've got it right, it will put them each in their own little column. Easy enough huh? But heres the thing, I want to put all these into an array to be stored in the 1 column (say called 'top3') and what's more have them clearly readable in PHPmyadmin and editable from there yet still be able to be called back an rendered on page when requested.

Continuing the example then, assuming I've changed the table for the 'top3' column instead of individual columns,  I could put something like this -

```
if (isset($_POST)['update_button']) {
    $top3_01 = $_POST['top3_01']; // i.e, 'bowling' changing POST vars to local vars
    $top3_02 = $_POST['top3_02']; // i.e, 'running'
    $top3_03 = $_POST['top3_03']; // i.e, 'diving'
    $top3_array = array($top3_01,$top3_02,$top3_03);
    include('connect_msql.php');

    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET top3='$top3_array' WHERE id='$id' AND blah blah blah");
```

But it will appear in the column as 'Array' and when its called for using a query it will render the literal string. a r r in each field instead.  Now I know you can use the `serialize()` & `unserialize()` functions but it makes the entry in the database practically unreadable. Is there a way to make it readable and editable without having to create a content management system?

If so please let me know and I'll be your friend forever, lol, ok maybe not but I'd really appreciate the help anyway.  The other thing is, If you can do this or something like it, how am I to add entries to that array to go back into the data base?

I hope I've explained myself enough here, but if not say so and I'll have another go.  Thanks very much people, Novice-ish.

Comment: Cheers for the edit progrmr, I'm going to close the book on this one now.  Much obliged to everyone for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 3):

**You are doing it wrong!**

What will happen, when you want to see all the users, who have set *'Music'* as `1st` priority in the interests ? Or what if you need to inform everyone with interest in *'Philately'*, that this has been merged into category *'Collecting stuff'*? And how would you even accomplish such a merge?

First: book recommendation: [**SQL Antipatterns**](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns). Buy it, steal it .. i don't care. Just read it.

Ok. Here is how, IMHO, this should be done. Lets begin:

### DB structure

You should recognie that each user has multiple interests, and each interst will (most likely) be related to more the one user. Thus, you need to create DB which reflects the [many-to-many](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) relationship between entities:

```
  Users           UserInterests         Interests
 -------         ----------------      --------------
| user_id  PK   | user_id  FK         | interest_id  PK
| name          | interest_id  FK     | title
| email         | priority            | ...
| ...                                 | etc.
| etc.
```

Primary keys and foreign keys are marked. If you do not know what they are ... read up.

### Few queries

As i do not really know how you will use that structure, i will just make up few example for you to see, how this setup can be used.

1. Getting list of user's interests:

   ```
   SELECT 
      UsersInterests.priority AS priority,
      Interests.title as interest
   FROM Users
      LEFT JOIN UserInterests USING (user_id)  
      LEFT JOIN Interests USING (interest_id)
   WHERE
      Users.name = 'FooBar'
   ```
2. Getting list of users who have at least 2 of given interests:

   ```
   SELECT 
       Users.user_id AS id,
       Users.name AS name,
       COUNT( UserInterests.interest_id ) AS similarities
   FROM Users
       LEFT JOIN UserInterests USING (user_id)
   WHERE UserInterests.interest_id IN ( 13, 42, 101)
   GROUP BY User.user_id
   HAVING similarities > 1
   ```
3. Finding users who have specific interest

   ```
   SELECT
      Users.user_id AS id,
      Users.name AS name,
      UserInterests.priority AS priority
   FROM Users
      LEFT JOIN UserInterests USING (user_id)
      LEFT JOIN Interests USING (interest_id)
   WHERE Interests.title = 'Phishing'
   ```
4. All the interests which have at least 4 times marked as 1st:

   ```
   SELECT 
       Interests.title AS interest,
       COUNT( UserInterests.user_id ) AS favorites
   FROM UserInterests
       LEFT JOIN Interests USING (interest_id)
   WHERE UserInterests.priority = 1
   GROUP BY UserInterests.interest_id
   HAVING favorites > 3
   ```

---

If you try to store all the user's top interests in a single field, you end up doing `LIKE` statements everywhere. It's bad for performance in short run, and disastrous, if you have to update the results in bulk .. and what if you decide to store top 5 results after a month?

Comment: Thanks. I was too lazy to write so much :) Yet I'd make this question favorite, so, I'll be able to refer to it in the future.

Comment: @ teresko - Thannks for your galient, guns blazing approach, lol.  Its a good post and I'm sure it will be useful for somebody, but I don't actually need to do any of that lot.  P.S I'm sure its right for whatever you were thinking of anyway. Cheers mate

Comment: @PHPLearner , you could have just written simply `TL;DR` .. as that's what you actually wrote.

Comment: LOL, Im still wondering what planet this guy is on! Ok, so to make this clear and you dont need to make anymore grand assumptions teresko Ill put it plainly.

Comment: "What will happen, when you want to see all the users, who have set 'Music' as 1st priority in the interests ? " - I dont need to do that. "Or what if you need to inform everyone with interest in 'Philately', that this has been merged into category 'Collecting stuff'?" - I dont need to do that. ".. and what if you decide to store top 5 results after a month? " - Guess what?  "TL;DR .. as that's what you actually wrote." - Too long, didnt read.. another grand assumption hey teresko?

Comment: Finally, Thanks again (and I really do mean that) for taking the time to write your post, Im sure it will be useful for somebody.

Answer (score -2):

You would need to join the array elements together with a character or character string which does not occur in the elements themselves.

You can join the three items together with:

```
$top3_string=mysql_escape_string(implode('::',$top3_array));
```

which would give you a string of:

```
bowling::running::diving
```

This would be easily editable in PHPMyAdmin and easily extractable using:

```
$top3_array=explode('::',$top3_string);
```

assuming that when you retrieve it in PHP you call the variable $top3_string

Comment: @ Dave - This was pretty much the answer I used except instead of using the :: as the delimiter I used a , . Does anyone agree that the php.net website is really difficult to understand? Im sure theres room in the market for a user friendly repository. Cheers for your reply anyway mate

Answer (score -2):

Use `join()` function.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET top3='".join(',', $top3_array' )." ...";
```

- Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php

Comment: @ Peter - Great mate, I'm going to try that when adding to the array!  I'll probably be back with more questions the next time I hit the wall, lol. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

you can also use string serialization. See a Example below:

```
$Communication2 = $_POST['Communication'];
    $N = count($abc);
$Communication = NULL;
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
    $Communication .= $Communication2[$i].",";
}
$Communication2 = serialize($_POST['Communication']);
```

Or Read here:

[String serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)
[String unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Goodluck

Comment: Isn't the bit in the middle with the loop completely useless? You set Communication2 to be the contents of $_POST['Communication'], join the elements together using commas and then just serialize $_POST['Communication'] (which is what the original poster did not want to do). Essentially, the middle loop does a `$Communication=implode(',',$_POST['Communication']);` but with more commands, a longer run time and the wrong result for the OP?

Comment: @DaveWilsonLAMP, Yes, now that you mentioned that, I misread that in the original post. Sorry for that though. I do use that on three websites to a large extent and with great success so I would not really change on that recipe, but that is personal preference.

Comment: @ Phoenix - Thanks for the effort to write anyway mate